# Entity Framework Navigation Property for a field that can store a foreign key from two different tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I need a table called Loan.

The columns of this table will be:
Id, Type, BorrowId, Description

The trick here is that Type field will determine whether the borrower is an Employee or a Customer and then the BorrowerId will either be an Id from the Employee table or an Id from the Customer table.

Is this bad design as far as Entity Framework is concerned? The reason I ask is because it seems like I won't be able to create a Borrower Navigation property on the Loan table since the Id can be from two tables.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Like how I can change my data models to work with Navigation properties.

Comment: If you know that this is known as *polymorphic associations* you'll see that there are many posts covering this. Take your pick.

Comment: This is the worst thing about working with databases now. Companies force application developers to do their best in a database environment with no knowledge of normal forms, RI, or any important database development concept. As a result you see a plethora of vendor applications that are left wide open for exploitation. It's a job that hasn't been defined yet to marry the two options.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer to your question is "Yes it's a bad design". Referential Integrity should be strictly enforced and when you remove that ability by alternating the reference you create a window for errors. If you want two options create two columns, and create foreign keys on each to the tables they reference. Then your application will be effectively foolproof. :D

Comment: Both columns would be nullable since it is one or the other correct?

Comment: I'm not a C# guru so the best answer I can give is that the class doesn't have a built in capability to differentiate between nullable and non nullable data types so you have to use additional logic in C# to handle those cases.

Comment: Yeah but what I was trying to say is that in SQL they would both me nullable if my business logic says one or the other right?

Comment: If your business logic dictates that there is a situation where a value could be null, that is absolute. As long as NULL is a possibility, then any situation that could contain the value should be considered nullable.